# K is a subgroup of G. Show that K is not a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

If $G = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} a,b\in (\mathbb{R}) : a \neq 0$)

and assume G is a group under matrix multpication

Assume that K = ($\begin{pmatrix} s & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}: s\in\mathbb{R}, s \neq 0$) is a subgroup of G. Prove that K is not a normal subgroup of G.

I have done some working out on this question which is the following:

$g^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} a^{-1}&-a^{-1}b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

and so

$$gkg^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}sa^{-1}&-a^{-1}bs\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

then we get
$$gkg^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}s&-bs+b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

What do I do from here, Why is $$gkg^{-1} \notin K$$
Can't I make b=0 and then it would be in K? or am I missing some key idea?

Comment: This would have to hold for *all* $b\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: wouldnt it still be an element for all b? if it isn't how come?

Comment: It would only be an element of $K$ for those $b$ that satisfy $-bs+b=0$. And this means $b=0$ or $s=1$. In particular, taking some $g$ such that $b\neq 0$, we always have $gkg^{-1}\notin K$ for $k\in K\setminus\{I_2\}$. Hence $K$ is not normal.

Comment: Ahh okay so it's only true when b=0 but generally this isn't true right?

Comment: You need to check your prose. You want to say perhaps "consider the group $G$ and the subgroup $K$" rather than "*assume* $G$ is a group and *assume* $K$ is a subgroup."

Comment: Fair point but the questions uses that terminology, I was mearly copying and pasting the question

Answer (score 0):

Let $b \neq 0$ and $s \neq 1$. Then

$\begin{bmatrix} s & b(1-s) \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} \notin K$, since $b(1-s) \neq 0$.

This shows that $K$ is not stable under conjugation by all elements of $G$, and so is not normal in $G$.